# Multi-language website having two databases

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently working on multi language website. It is hosted in different 4 locations (countries), having dedicated database for each. Its working fine.
And the project uses EF6.

The website has a Menu with properties like MenuOrder, Visible etc.
I do not want to set these properties to set for each location individually. It should be set in DBKey database only.

Is it possible to achieve that each location uses two databases:

1. DBKeys : Only for Keys (Common to all location)
2. DBResx : only for translations.

Currently using single context. Is it possible to use two contexts for same having foreign key relations in different context?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use two contexts for same having foreign key relations in different context?

Yes it is certainly possible to use two contexts for same application having foreign key relations in different context. But there are two situations for this:

- Two contexts of a single databases
- Two contexts of two different databases

I think you are talking about the second situation here, so I think you will just want to use unique Primary Keys that are also used as foreign Keys because you can not create relations in tables from different databases and you will have to form those relations in your application layer and probably use triggers and stored procedures in your database for consistency.

I recently answered a question about join accross different contexts here is the code as an example for you:

```
public IQueryable<ActivityRegister> GetRegisters(int activityID) 
{
    var activityRegisters = ActivityDBContext.ActivityRegisters.Where(x => x.ActivityID == activityID x.IsActive == true).OrderBy(x => x.ActivityRegisterID).ToList();
    var roomIdsFromActivityRegisters = activityRegisters.Select(activityRegister => activityRegister.roomID);
    var rooms = AdminDBContext.Rooms.Where(room => roomsIdFromActivityRegisters.Contains(room.Id)).ToList();
    var resultFromJoinAcrossContexts = (from activityRegister in activityRegisters 
                                        join room in rooms on activityRegister.roomID equals room.Id
                                        select new ActivityRegister
                                        {
                                            Room = room,
                                            roomID = room.Id,
                                            Id = activityRegister
                                         });
    return resultFromJoinAcrossContexts.AsQueryable();
}
```

As you can see in this code that all you will have to do perform a join accross different contexts will be to pull down the data from the database into the memoery and then perform the join.

**Additional link:**

[One Database or Ten?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/merrill_aldrich/archive/2011/11/25/one-database-or-ten.aspx)